# Javascript - Show a div with a given class after clicking on a given class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Several spans that have certain classes.

```
<span class="1 click-1">1</span>
<span class="2 click-2">2</span>
<span class="3 click-3">4</span>
<span class="4 click-4">4</span>
```

Clicking on a given `<span>` displays a DIV that contains the same class. How to do it?

```
<div class="click-1">Hello!</div>
<div class="click-2">Hello 2!</div>
<div class="click-3">Hello 3!</div>
<div class="click-4">Hello 4!</div>
```

I need such a solution because it is development on the CMS side. User can add much more span and div. So the script has to be universal.

Comment: The div's are already visible. Why will you want to show them again? Or you want to show related div and hide the rest?

Comment: You're not helping yourself with the semantic class names.   Give them *all* a single class so you can do `$(".clickable").hide()` and then give give them a pair of data-id= (not id=) then `$(".clickable").hide();$(".clickable[data-id=" + $(this).data(id) + "]").show()` otherwise you have to do *tedious* (and error prone) class parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(e => {
  e.onclick = () => {                          // on click on span
    const div = document.createElement("div"); // create new div
    div.classList = e.classList;               // copy and reuse class list
    div.innerText = `Hello ${e.innerText}!`;   // set inner text to 'Hello ${}!'
    document.body.append(div);                 // append div to dom
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="1 click-1">1</span>
<span class="2 click-2">2</span>
<span class="3 click-3">4</span>
<span class="4 click-4">4</span>
Clicking on a given <span> displays a DIV that contains the same class. How to do it?
```

Comment: I think you've taken the *sample* provided far too literally.   It's more likely the DIVs are pre-created with *actual content* rather than generated with "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Since JQuery is tagged, points to note is that only the span's 2nd class name will be used to find div with same classes in code below.

```
$(document).on("click","span",function(){// attaching evt listner to all spans
  var getClass = $(this).prop('class').split(' ')[1];//get 2nd classname of span
    $(`div.${getClass}`).show(); // divs with such class
    //or
    $(`.${getClass}`).show(); // anything with such class
});
```

This code will work with the html syntax given above. But in cases where there are just one class in a span then it will not work. So modify the code accordingly or make sure the second class of span is equal to classname of div you are trying to show.

Answer (score -1):

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('click-1');
var testDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function(testElement){
  return testElement.nodeName === 'DIV';
});
```

Comment: It is not global.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.